# Android Studio. Не отображает Navigation Drawer при нажатии на гамбургер

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-toolbar, android-navigation-drawer

В Debugger при нажатие на гамбургер item равно ActionMenuItem@4876, как выправить код чтоб все заработало?

```
private void setToolBar() {

        Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(tb);

        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_default);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.forecast_filter:
            showFiter();
            break;
        case R.id.home: {
            dLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;}
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы используете неправильный ID. Вам надо вместо

> R.id.home

использовать системный ID из пакета `android`, т.е.

```
android.R.id.home
```

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало!!! Главное что пробовал так вчера и не хотело...

Comment: @ТарасЖупник, скорее всего у вас не работало, т.к. у вас в студии включена настройка `InstantRun`, которая не перезапускает/пересобирает приложение при изменениях в коде, а пытается адаптировать уже запущенное под изменённый код. Эта функция работает очень плохо, отключите её. А через 8 мин. вы сможете отметить ответ верным, нажав на галочку слева от его тела)

Comment: я ждал чтоб отметить))), спасибо